# GWT History - newItem(String historyToken, boolean issueEvent ) broken in FF41

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-history

Looks like GWT `History#newItem(String, boolean)` method with `boolean` parameter which is controlling value change event has been broken even though passed `false` value, in most recent firefox release (particularly 41)

Is anyone persisting same issue? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Probably yes. Raise a ticket.